# Elixir: Find the most common element (frequency) in a list of tuples?

Tags: list, tuples, elixir, element, frequency

I am aware this is a common question on stackoverflow, but cannot find a solution specifically for Elixir.

Consider the list of tuples:

```
[
  {1, 3, "1S"},
  {10, 3, "3S"},
  {10, 3, "9S"},
  {10, 3, "10S"},
  {10, 3, "11S"},
  {12, 3, "12S"},
  {13, 3, "13S"}
]
```

Expected results:
The most common element in the first parameter for each tuple is 10.
The most common element in the second parameter for each tuple is 3.

Is there a function that does this, or must I create my own function that "iterates" through the list of tuples for each `elem(list, index)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine [`Enum.frequencies_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies_by/2) and [`Enum.max_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#max_by/4) to get the most frequent element:

```
iex(2)> x |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, 0)) |> Enum.max_by(&elem(&1, 1))
{10, 4}
iex(3)> x |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, 1)) |> Enum.max_by(&elem(&1, 1))
{3, 7}
iex(4)> x |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, 2)) |> Enum.max_by(&elem(&1, 1))
{"10S", 1}
```

Note that, since `frequencies_by` returns a map (and maps are unordered), it is undefined which element gets returned by `max_by` if there is a tie, as you can see in the last example.

Comment: This shows how to compute a single element, but not all of them. I added an answer that applies this to all the tuple elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is not as straightforward, though. Somewhat alongside lines  below would work.

```rb
input = [
  {1, 3, "1S"},
  {10, 3, "3S"},
  {10, 3, "9S"},
  {10, 3, "10S"},
  {10, 3, "11S"},
  {12, 3, "12S"},
  {13, 3, "13S"}
]

input
# prepare to transpose a matrix
|> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
# transpose
|> fn mx -> List.zip(mx) |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1) end.()
# group by value, to get to lengths 
|> Enum.map(&Enum.group_by(&1, fn e -> e end))
# get max values
|> Enum.map(&Enum.max_by(&1, fn {_, v} -> length(v) end))
# collect
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, length(v)} end)      

#⇒ [{10, 4}, {3, 7}, {"10S", 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers are good. This is just an alternative if you want to get an overview of all frequencies without knowing the size of the tuple in advance (which should never happen):

```
input = [
  {1, 3, "1S"},
  {10, 3, "3S"},
  {10, 3, "9S"},
  {10, 3, "10S"},
  {10, 3, "11S"},
  {12, 3, "12S"},
  {13, 3, "13S"}
]

input
|> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
|> Enum.reduce(
  %{},
  fn listy, final_map ->
    listy
    |> Enum.with_index()
    |> Enum.reduce(final_map, fn {element, index}, acc ->
      acc
      |> Map.update(index, %{element => 1}, fn existing_value ->
        existing_value |> Map.update(element, 1, fn existing_element -> existing_element + 1 end)
      end)
    end)
  end
)
|> IO.inspect(label: "map with 'tuple element index' as keys and 'map of element frequencies' as values")
```

Answer (score 1):

Legoscia's answer tells you how to calculate the most common value for a single index, but it does not show how to compute that for all elements of the tuple.

Here is is a version that uses that to compute the most common element at each tuple index - it works for tuples of any length (assuming all tuples in the list are the same length).

```elixir
def most_common_elems([]), do: %{}

def most_common_elems([first | _] = list) do
  max_i = tuple_size(first) - 1
  Map.new(0..max_i, &most_common_at(list, &1))
end

def most_common_at(list, i) do
  max_val =
    list
    |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, i))
    |> Enum.max_by(&elem(&1, 1))
    |> elem(0)

  {i, max_val}
end
```

Example output:

```elixir
%{0 => 10, 1 => 3, 2 => "10S"}
```